# Python : Calculating probability of a dice throw function

Tags: python, probability, dice

Hello this is a question I have been tasked with.
..........................................................................................................
You are at the bottom of a staircase with a die. With each throw of the die, you
either move down one step (if you get a 1 or 2 on the dice) or move up one step (if you get a
3, 4, or 5 on the dice). If you throw a 6 on the die, you throw the die again and move up the
staircase by the number you get on that second throw. Note if you are at the base of the
staircase, you cannot move down!
The function has a parameter that takes a probability distribution over all
outcomes from a dice throw. For example (0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1) would suggest that the
probability of getting a 1 is 0.2, 2 is 0.3 etc. Calculate the probability of reaching a step
higher than the 200th one for the following case: 100 throws, [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1] distribution.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
I have been able to create some code which serves as the function (I'm sure it could be simplified but I am new to this) however I am unsure as to how to work out the probability of it being higher than the 200th step.

```
import random

def rolldice(T:int, D): #T = throws, D = distribution in format [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1] [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1]
  Stair = 0

  for i in range(T):
    print(i,Stair)
    roll = random.choices([1,2,3,4,5,6], weights= D)
    roll2 = random.choices([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    roll1 = roll[0]
    if roll[0] == 1 and Stair > 0:
     Stair -= 1
    elif roll[0] == 2 and Stair > 0:
     Stair -= 1
    elif roll[0] == 3:
     Stair += 1
    elif roll[0] == 4:
     Stair += 1
    elif roll[0] == 5:
     Stair += 1
    elif roll[0] == 6:
     Stair += roll2[0]

  return Stair
  
rolldice(100, [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1])
```

Comment: So run it 1000 times and count how often you end up above stair 200.  Note that you can combine those ifs: `if roll1 in (1,2) and Stair > 0:` and `if roll1 in (3,4,5):`.  Also, you shouldn't actually do the second roll until you know you got a 6.

Comment: Thanks for your Notes I have implemented them into the code. How would you suggest to get the code to run 1000 times?

Comment: Put the last line in a `for` loop that runs 1000 times. Save the return value from the function call. If the return value is greater than 200 then increment a counter. Finally, after that `for` loop, divide the counter by 1000. Use variables instead of hard coded values for 200 and 1000 - then you can easily change the assignments  to try different things.

Answer (score -1):

You could assign T to 1000 by an input function and it would then loop for a certain amount of throws.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem.  T=100 is part of the spec.  He needs to run those 100 throws many times.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).